# How many 100 sq km bounding boxes cover the surface are of the earth.

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, spheres

I need to figure out how many 100 square km bounding boxes cover the surface area of the earth. I'm trying to use the Instagram API to download data. Their API supports a lat/long with a maximum distance of 5 km. So I have an algorithm that given a lat/long and offset, can move the boundary left or up until all the surface area of earth is covered.

Comment: What boundary are you moving?

Comment: Is a bounding box always 10 km by 10 km?  How do you deal with the spherical nature of the earth, though at that scale it doesn't matter much.  What is your model of the earth surface?   A sphere, the reference ellipsoid, or other?

Comment: The bounding box is always 10 km by 10 km. My model of the earth surface is a perfect sphere (I don't need to be that accurate in my estimations). I guess, another way of asking this question is: is there a formula for approximating how many square patches cover the surface area of a sphere?

Comment: You know you can't tile a sphere with perfect squares. So what are you willing to give up? Do the patches have to be 100 sq km exactly? Does each point on the Earth have to be in exactly one patch? Or an the patches overlap? How many sides have to be exactly 10km long?